# Google Maps URL Tile Server API and Documentation?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I would like to use Google Maps tiles for maps inside of my [Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com) projects.  There are currently [18 Google Maps APIs](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?filter=category:maps) and I think I need the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/).  However, this API appears to return whole maps instead of individual tiles.

Which API do I need for use as a URL tile server for the [`GeoServer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoServer.html) option in the Wolfram Language [Maps & Cartography](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MapsAndCartography.html) functions?  Also, where is there official documentation of the URL tile server in Google's documentation?

## Update

From @ChrisDegnen answer below I think the Static Map API is the only option.  However. I wanted to use the map as a background to the existing Maps & Cartography functions in the Wolfram Language.  Unfortunately, the Static Map API does not allow explicit specification of the lat-long boundaries so it is not a good fit.

For example to map the continental USA using the `"visible`" parameter to set the map bounds.

```
visible =
 StringReplace["\n" -> "|"]@
  ExportString[
   Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ GeoBounds[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]]], 1], 
   "CSV"]
```

> ```
> "25.1246466,-124.733151|25.1246466,-66.949806|49.3844900814454,-124.733151|49.3844900814454,-66.949806|"
> ```

The Static Map API returns [this map](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x300&visible=25.1246466,-124.733151%7C25.1246466,-66.949806%7C49.3844900814454,-124.733151%7C49.3844900814454,-66.949806%7C) (my personal key having been removed).

```
URLExecute["http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap",
 {
  "size" -> "600x300",
  "visible" -> visible,
  "key"-> "mykey" 
  }
 ]
```

[image]

The Static Map API adds far too much padding when compared to the default [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html) map.

```
GeoGraphics[{Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]},
 ImageSize -> {600, 300}]
```

[image]

This extra padding will throw off anything I add to the map in my code.  So in the end I can't use the Google maps.

Comment: You are only allowed to access Google Maps Tiles through the Google Maps API.

Comment: @geocodezip Yes, I know I need to use the API.  I am asking which API I need to use to get the tiles.

Comment: I don't see how this question could be closed for being too broad.  It is a very narrow question on a specific bit of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mathematica documentation demonstrates use of the Static Maps API, if that's any help.

https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/url-manipulation/call-urls-like-functions.html

```
URLExecute[
 "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap",
 {"center" -> "Brooklyn Bridge,New York,NY",
  "zoom" -> "13", "size" -> "600x300"}, "Method" -> "GET"]
```

[image]

Comment: I think I agree that the Static Map API is the only way to do this but it does not give me enough control of visible area of the map. I don't think I can use it. However, it is the closest to the result.